# Trouble with date format when comparing two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime column that i'm trying to compare with a date value in the DD/MM/YYYY format.

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATETIME_COLUMN, '%d/%m/%Y') = '04/04/2014'.
```

It doesn't work.

Even tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME_COLUMN = '04/04/2014'
```

Which seems to be working on the rest of my code, but it doesn't.

Is there another function?

Comment: Did you try to convert your DD/MM/YYYY date into a sane format?

Comment: Why don't you convert your *input* to a `datetime` value, instead of converting every `datetime` value to text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using this query which will keep you predicate sargable.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATETIME_COLUMN = STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

if your `DATETIME_COLUMN` column has time part and you want to get all dates within given date, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATETIME_COLUMN >= STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
  AND DATETIME_COLUMN < STR_TO_DATE('05/04/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: +1 for doing it the right way. You should also convert the second one to a `DATE_ADD(... INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. Otherwise OP will have to perform date math on the DD/MM/YYYY string, which will probably not go well...

Comment: @Vatev, but passing two arguments in to query is more flexible, because it is giving opportunity to filter data within the date interval.Of course  it is also possible by passing start day and interval. So, depends on requirements.

Comment: True, but in my experience when you have two date (without time) arguments which define a range, the users expect the range to be inclusive. Because of that, at some point 1 day will be added to the end date.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATETIME_COLUMN,'%d/%m/%Y') = '04/04/2014';
```